# installed application from Android Studio opens another activity instead of launcher activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, launcher, run-app

Whenever I run my app from Android studio, an Activity having

```
android:exported="true"
```

get's launched instead of launcher activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But once app installed, correct launcher activity opens, no issue.
Only issue happens when I launch my app from Android studio(i.e. by running the app). So why this happens?

Without `android:exported="true"`, on some devices, that activity not gets launched after clicking notification of my app. So is it good to keep exported true?

Also I can't post my entire manifest here

Comment: manifest.xml, launcher activity code please

Comment: perhaps check your run configuration? Run -> Edit Configurations

Comment: "Without android:exported="true", on some devices, that activity not gets launched after clicking notification of my app" -- that is a separate problem. You should not need to export your activity to have it be opened via a `PendingIntent` used by a `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare not separate problem, but wanted to tell that's the reason why I have added android:exported="true" for that activity, and wanted to know is there any other alternative to android:exported="true"

Comment: "wanted to know is there any other alternative to android:exported="true"" -- use `android:exported="false"`. If you are having problems with that on some devices, post a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] and an explanation of what problems you are having on what devices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it only happens in Android Studio and not when the app is installed, it is most likely a problem with the run configuration. You can access it by going to

Run -> Edit Configurations

Answer (score 0):

When running the app from Android Studio, you're probably using instant run. which applies the code changes to the current running process of your app, so instead of installing the app again, it applies the new changes to the running app, in that case you see the current running activity as it is.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.eg/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html